# No module named vim

Tags: python, vim

I've been trying to use clang_format.py to format my files. The first few lines are the following :

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import difflib
import json
import os.path
import platform
import subprocess
import sys 
import vim
```

When running the file, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nweeks/coding/draft/.clang-format.py", line 48, in <module>
    import vim
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vim'
```

I checked on the internet to no avail, the usual issue is that vim was not installed with python. Here's my vim -version :

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       +tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
+balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
+browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     +perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   +toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
+clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          +ruby              +wildignore
+cursorbind        +lua               +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con_gui    +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      +sodium            +X11
+digraphs          +mouse             +sound             -xfontset
+dnd               +mouseshape        +spell             +xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       +xpm
+emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary        
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
```

As you can see, I have +python3 but -python, but I can't see how to get -python (it feels outdated now).
I use python3.10.6, and I also have python2.7 installed. Whichever version of python I use, I get the same error. What am I missing here?

Comment: Module `vim` is a module of Python **builtin into the vim**. You cannot install it and import it in the code running in an external Python like in `:!python .clang-format.py`. You can only access it from the builtin Python: `:pyfile .clang-format.py`. See [help on `:pyfile`](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html#:pyfile) and [`:py3file`](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html#:py3file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module `vim` is a module of Python **builtin into the `vim`**. You cannot install it and import it in code running in an external Python like in `:!python .clang-format.py`. You can only access it from the builtin Python:

```
:pyfile .clang-format.py
```

See [help on `:pyfile`](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html#:pyfile) and [`:py3file`](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html#:py3file).

Answer (score -3):

well simply just install it in the terminal

install 1

> $ sudo apt-get update

install 2

> $ sudo apt-get install vim

Or just run in the classic way

> pip install vim

if it dont work then its probely something wrong
with your package then and try to
fix it with

try:

import vim

except:

print("Vim package is still wrong please call the owner")

Comment: You cannot install `vim` with `pip`: https://pypi.org/project/vim — error 404. Module `vim` is a module of Python **builtin into the vim editor**.